# ChipGroup for older android version

Tags: android, android-api-levels, android-chips

i made an app and realized that it doesnt work for older versions cause ChipGroup only works for api level >= 28. I found multiple tutorials that show how to solve this but sadly it didnt work. Is there maybe another way to get a similiar result?

Example of my current solution with api level 29:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks,
Gwinzy

Comment: I have app with min sdk 24 and ChipGroup works just fine. Is your project using AndroidX [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate]

Comment: yes, it is androidX already. but the min sdk is 19

Comment: The `minSdkVersion` of the Material Components for Android appears to be 14. See [the `1.1.0` version](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/build.gradle#L96) for example.